# Failing to push docker image using gcloud app deploy

Tags: node.js, docker, authorization, web-deployment, gcloud

I am trying to deploy an Node.js application in GCP using Google Cloud SDK. 
I'm a beginner so I'm using the basic deploy command.

```
gcloud app deploy
```

I never had an issue for the past three months but I start to get this error.

```
    Step #1: INFO[0101] Taking snapshot of full filesystem...
    Step #1: INFO[0131] CMD npm start
    Step #1: error pushing image: failed to push to destination us.gcr.io/my_project_name_here/appengine/default.20191124t210632:latest: DENIED: "Access denied."
    Finished Step #1
    ERROR
    ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor@sha256:f87c11770a4d3ed33436508d206c584812cd656e6ed08eda1cff5c1ee44f5870" failed: exit status 1
```

It pushes everything successfully to the staging bucket. However, it gets the 'Access Denied' error when it tries to push to the main bucket for the web app.

I haven't changed any permissions or roles for any service accounts.
I compared the permission for both buckets and all the service accounts listed are the same, with the same permissions for both staging and main buckets.

I do not have any custom docker image that I'm trying to deploy if that helps.

Has anyone had this issue before? If so, please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: can you show us the command you used to deploy the app ?

Comment: You should show us the full command you are using to deploy the function as Sameer mentioned, also, it may be useful to add the [--verbosity="debug"](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--verbosity) flag to the command in order to get more information on where it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled and re-enabled my application. And now it's working with no issue. Thank you, guys!